issues with [%0] in SAP B1 Hana Query
I used [%0] to call a selection criteria on SAP B1 that looks like this:

The query looks like this:
    SELECT 
        'Handshake' AS "Link"
    FROM OITM T0
    WHERE T0."ItmsGrpCod" = '[%2]'

It works like normal even when I did something like this:
WITH
tahoon as (
    SELECT 
        A."Name",
        'Handshake' as "Link" 
        FROM "@TAHUN" A
    WHERE A."Name" = '[%0]'
),
tahoon2 as (
    SELECT 
       A."Name", 
        'Handshake' as "Link"
    FROM "@TAHUN" A
    WHERE A."Name" = '[%1]'
),
tahoon3 as (
    SELECT 
        A."Name", 
        'Handshake' as "Link"
    FROM "@TAHUN" A
    WHERE A."Name" = '[%2]'
)

    SELECT 
        THN."Name" as "tahun1",
        B."Name" as "tahun2",
        C."Name" as "tahun3",
        THN."Link"
    FROM tahoon2 THN
    INNER JOIN 
        tahoon B
            ON 
                THN."Link" = b."Link"
    INNER JOIN 
        tahoon3 C
            ON 
                b."Link" = C."Link"

The problem starts to arise when I tried to link FROM OITB A instead of FROM "@TAHUN" A in the block of tahoon3, like this:
WITH
tahoon as (
    SELECT 
        A."Name",
        'Handshake' as "Link" 
        FROM "@TAHUN" A
    WHERE A."Name" = '[%0]'
),
tahoon2 as (
    SELECT 
       A."Name", 
        'Handshake' as "Link"
    FROM "@TAHUN" A
    WHERE A."Name" = '[%1]'
),
tahoon3 as (
    SELECT 
        A."ItmsGrpCod", 
        'Handshake' as "Link"
    FROM OITB A
    WHERE A."ItmsGrpCod" = '[%2]'
)

    SELECT 
        THN."Name" as "tahun1",
        B."Name" as "tahun2",
        C."ItmsGrpCod" as "tahun3",
        THN."Link"
    FROM tahoon2 THN
    INNER JOIN 
        tahoon B
            ON 
                THN."Link" = b."Link"
    INNER JOIN 
        tahoon3 C
            ON 
                b."Link" = C."Link"

It only procs the last error I had which doesn't help at all at debugging.
But when I changed [%2] into 111 it works perfectly fine.
Where is the problem?
Why does 111 works perfectly fine?
Why does OITB doesn't work when it's supposed to?
I expect it to work when it logically should work.
Edit: No, I cant use DECLARE or SET since it will result in this on creating a report :


at this point im starting to wonder if the problem lies in [%0] cant be used in a CTE

what error do you get if rewritten using Join and sub query instead of CTE ?

@Praxiom same error
